# Timer doesn't work properly swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

In my app I setup timers with different timeInterval for each cell in tableView, I create array of timers, created function setTimer that returns Timer and prepareForReuse to invalidate timers here is my custom table view cell class

```
class cellForData: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var iconImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var dataText: UILabel!


var timerArray: Array = [Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer(), Timer()]


var count: Double = 0
var texts = String()

var countHowMuch = Double()

func setTimer(withInterval: Double, text: String, countTimes: Double) -> Timer {
    texts = text
    countHowMuch = countTimes
    return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: withInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(handle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func handle() {
    count += countHowMuch
    dataText.text = "\(count) + \(texts)"
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    timerArray[timerArray.count - 1].invalidate()
}


}
```

In ViewController I call function setTimer inside cellForRow function here is code for that

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondVCCell") as? cellForData {
        cell.timerArray[indexPath.row] = cell.setTimer(withInterval: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].seconds, text: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].text, countTimes: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].countTimes)
        RunLoop.main.add(cell.timerArray[indexPath.row], forMode: .commonModes)

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()

}
```

So when table view scrolled cells behave strange, those cells always change position and after that timers don't work properly, I guess timers don't even invalidate. I need timers invalidate whenever cell reuses and cells stay at the same position. Here is my whole view controller

```
import UIKit
```

struct forShowedVC {
    var image: UIImage!
    var text: String!
    var seconds: Double!
    var countTimes: Double!
}

class showedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var arrayOfAStruct = [forShowedVC]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self

    arrayOfAStruct = [forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "a", seconds: 1, countTimes: 3),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "b", seconds: 1, countTimes: 2),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "c", seconds: 1, countTimes: 7),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "d", seconds: 1, countTimes: 12),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "e", seconds: 1, countTimes: 1),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "f", seconds: 1, countTimes: 9),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "g", seconds: 1, countTimes: 13),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "h", seconds: 1, countTimes: 71),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "i", seconds: 1, countTimes: 4),
                      forShowedVC(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pie-chart"), text: "j", seconds: 1, countTimes: 6)]
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondVCCell") as? cellForData {
        cell.timerArray[indexPath.row] = cell.setTimer(withInterval: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].seconds, text: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].text, countTimes: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].countTimes)
        RunLoop.main.add(cell.timerArray[indexPath.row], forMode: .commonModes)

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfAStruct.count
}


}
```

Comment: your question is not that much clear can you please elaborate in detail. and want to specify the cellForRowAt always call number of times so thats why it is causing issue.

Comment: Note that having a timer run on every cell that calls reloadData() is bad practice. You're reloading the entire table view every time any cell's timer fires. You should figure out which cells have changed and only reload those cells using `reloadRows(at:with:)`.

Comment: I changed everything can you please revise

Comment: Timers _do_ work properly in Swift. It is _you_ who is doing something wrong.

Comment: oh really? @matt

Comment: Really. The title "Timer doesn't work properly in Swift" is both meaningless and false.

Comment: "Timer doesn't work properly swift". There is no "in" there. At the end of the title word swift means that I code using swift, not that timer doesn't work In swift @matt

Comment: Timer is language independent. Call it Timer, call it NSTimer, call it whatever. IT WORKS. Trust me. If there's a problem, the mistake is _yours_, not a bug in Timer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you dequeue a cell you create a new timer, but never invalidate any of them. As a result, when you scroll your code keeps adding more and more timers. Here's what I would do to fix that:

Modify your table view cell class to have a timer property that is a weak optional:

```
@class cellForData: UITableViewCell {

  weak var cellTimer: Timer?

//Your other vars and code here
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAt method, dequeue a cell and immediately invalidate it's timer:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondVCCell") as? cellForData {
    cell.cellTimer?.invalidate()
    cell.cellTimer = setTimer(withInterval: arrayOfAStruct[indexPath.row].seconds, selector: #selector(handleObject))
    //The rest of your code to configure the cell goes here.
}
```

By making the cell's `cellTimer` a weak optional, the only strong reference to the timer is held by the run loop while the timer is running. If you invalidate it, it gets released and set to nil. Thus, the optional chaining in the code `cell.cellTimer?.invalidate()` doesn't do anything if the cell does not have a running timer.

You could also put the call to `cell.cellTimer?.invalidate()` in your table view cell's `prepareForReuse()` method instead of in `cellForRowAt`